# Dealing with django settings.py file after adding to .gitignore?

Tags: django, git, pycharm, gitignore

I added the `settings.py` file of my django project to `.gitignore` before pushing to Github.

Now when I open the project in PyCharm, the file name `settings.py` is highlighted in a kind of lime green color.

Is this telling me something else or are there any other implications for this other than having added it to .gitignore, maybe in terms of later on when I want to put my site on a remote server for instance?

I will probably push new commits to Github in the future so I had planned to keep it in .gitignore, but would this present any other problems?

Comment: The IDE just highlights the files in `.gitignore` to present a visual cue. Should not affect anything else.

Comment: Does it highlight files for any other reason other than due to their being in .gitignore (I mean aside from highlighting in red to flag files with errors)?

Comment: Nope. In editors like VS Code/Codium, it changes it to a muted grey to indicate it is ignored.